# passing the particular value from the jsp to Spring mvc controller to find particular record

Tags: java, spring, html, jsp

> creating spring mvc project with @cotroller class.. created patient entity,DAO layer, and service layer and Controller.. everything is perfect in my code. I am struggling for passing the single value from the jsp page to controller,  this is my front controller class code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/patient")
public class PatientController {

    @Autowired
    PatientService patientService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/showpatient/{tokenNumber}")
    public ModelAndView getProduct(@PathVariable int tokenNumber) {
        Patient patient = patientService.patientVerifyByTokenumber(tokenNumber);
        return new ModelAndView("VerifyingPatient", "patient", patient);
    } 
}
```

> This is my `Jsp` page code.. with help of tokenNumber, I have to find particular patient. I am trying to pass the token number in `jsp` page, but got an exception.

```
<form:form action="showpatient/${patient.tokenNumber}" modelAttribute="patient"
        method="GET">
Enter the token number
<form:input path="tokenNumber"></form:input>
        <input type="submit" value="verify" />
 </form:form>

<b>Token Number:</b> ${patient.tokenNumber}<br>
<b>Patient Name:</b>${patient.patientName}<br>
<b>patient Age:</b>${patient.patientAge}<br>
<b>Phone Number:</b>${patient.phoneNumber}<br>
```

> when I hit the verify button, get this type of exception:

```
Oct 10, 2018 10:01:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [application] in context with path [/SpringMVC_Assesment] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/views/VerifyingPatient.jsp] at line [48]

45:  <form:form action="showpatient/${patient.tokenNumber}" modelAttribute="patient"
46:         method="GET">
47: Enter the token number
48: <form:input path="tokenNumber"></form:input>
49:         <input type="submit" value="verify" />
50:  </form:form>
51:  


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'patient' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.VerifyingPatient_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(VerifyingPatient_jsp.java:269)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.VerifyingPatient_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(VerifyingPatient_jsp.java:227)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.VerifyingPatient_jsp._jspService(VerifyingPatient_jsp.java:153)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/showpatient/{tokenNumber}")
    public String getProduct(@PathVariable int tokenNumber, Model model) { 
     Patient patient = patientService.patientVerifyByTokenumber(tokenNumber);
        model.addAttribute("patient", patient); 
        return "VerifyingPatient"; 
    }
```

Comment: my controller code is working fine.. but getting exception from jsp page

Comment: Yes, because your jsp doesn't get patient as an attribute. See your error "**** nor plain target object for bean name 'patient' available as request attribute". Therefore, you have to provide patient as an attribute.

Comment: i tried yours code , again i got same error.. actually error comes from jsp page